# Grails - @Transactional annotation on generating simple Controller

Tags: grails

Grails newb here. I was using GGTS to generate a controller for a simple User model (string user, string passed)

On looking at the GGTS generated code, I noticed that there is @Transactional annotation on certain actions like delete(), save() and update().

My question is, why is @Transactional used in the controller and why is @Transactional not used in Services?

Newb in grails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In grails the correct way to do all DB related work and DB transactions is to do in service classes and not controllers. So by default controllers don't have privileges to do transaction and hence we use @Transactional annotation. While in services by default transaction is allowed.

If you use a service method which does some DB transaction then you need to make your controller action transactional by @Transactional annotation. While no need to mention it in service method.

Other way round if you donot make the controller transactional then you will need to mention it in service class.

Best practice will be not to use auto generated code as it will be less maintainable for a beginner. Official documentation will be your best help and while doing it when you will create controller you will not find any transactional annotation while when you will create service class you will see transactional annotation at the class level.

P.S. - 'Create' class is not equal to 'generate'.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. I am still quite dependent on generated code. Hoping to learn from it.

Comment: Ok then do one thing if you have some extra time then generate code for what you need and try to implement the same yourself. Do remember ajax based forms and stuff will be your best friends in your grails journey. And none of the ajax stuff is used in generated code. You can also get help form gsp tags for ajax like formRemote and learn them gradually. Also you will need to send back your data as JSON(most easiest way) using `render someResultVariable as JSON`